# Opening http connection : android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: java, android

I have trouble opening an http connection in an Android app.

Here is my Android Studio code :

```
    try {
        String address = "http://example.com/test.php";
        URL url = new URL(address);

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.connect();

        //Crashes on this.
        OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
        String data  = URLEncoder.encode("x", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(10), "UTF-8");

        bufferedWriter.write(data);
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        OS.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My crash:

> 04-24 16:48:24.848 13860-13860/com.example.benas.testingpurposes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                      Process: com.example.benas.testingpurposes, PID: 13860
>                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.benas.testingpurposes/com.example.benas.testingpurposes.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
>                                                                                       Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                                          at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
>                                                                                          at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
>                                                                                          at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
>                                                                                          at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
>                                                                                          at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
>                                                                                          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
>                                                                                          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
>                                                                                          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:361)
>                                                                                          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
>                                                                                          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
>                                                                                          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
>                                                                                          at com.example.benas.testingpurposes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

I'm stuck with it, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Use MySQLi prepared statements. 
Read this link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php. 

Also escape your input data before inserting into database. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to solution to this problem.
To fix this problem you need to run this code snippet on another thread.
You are welcome :). Once again it was really silly mistake

Comment: Bretty much. If you write your own custom ASyncTask that sets up the connection based on an url once you can copy paste it to future projects. The standard connection library has a host of problems though, you're better off with a more modern library like android's Volley for more futureproof connections.